# Excel cell name number adding

Tags: excel

I am very confuse to explain by question/problem, I will my best to do so.

I want to write a formula just to display a value from another cell by jumping the cell in a particular sequence.

```
e.g.
Column D
=A1
=A6
=A11
=A16
-----
----
-----
```

It is a sequence of 5 cells
I write the two rows formula as =A1 and =A6 and drag the formula and I got as

```
=A1
=A6
=A3
=A8
```

Anyone please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`OFFSET()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/offset-HP005209208.aspx) and [`ROW()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/row-HP005209244.aspx)

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*5,0)
```

Paste it in `D1` and copy down

As an example if you were to have in `A` values that correspond to a row numbers then you'll get the following sample outcome

```
A  | B  | C  |   D
------------------
1  |    |    |   1
2  |    |    |   6
3  |    |    |  11
4  |    |    |  16
5  |    |    |  21
6  |    |    |  26
7  |    |    |  31
8  |    |    |  36
9  |    |    |  41
...
```

**Explanation:**

> `OFFSET()` returns a reference to a range that is a specified number of rows and columns from a cell or range of cells.
>   `ROW()` returns the row number of a reference.

Therefore the formula will be evaluated to:

- for `D1` - Go  0 ((1-1)*5) rows and 0 columns from `A1` which is `A1` itself (1+0)
- for `D2` - Go  5 ((2-1)*5) rows and 0 columns from `A1` which is `A6` (1+5)
- for `D3` - Go 10 ((3-1)*5) rows and 0 columns from `A1` which is `A11`(1+10)
- etc

Comment: hi @peterm - sorry for my late reply. It helps me out. If u don't mind I need a small help again. Can u please explain your formula. I was again trying to display starting from A10 with a sequence of 9 but unable.

Comment: @Beginner You're very welcome :) See updated answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the worksheet formulae indirect + row

```
=INDIRECT("A"&((ROW(A1)-1)*5+1))
```

So, it looks up the row that we're in, subtracts 1, multiplies by 5, and adds one.

Cheers.